# ios how to manage DB with iphone app version by version?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, ipad, sqlite

My question contains two ways:
1. For example I have an app which is on appstore and containing sqlite database. After sometime I want to update app version without changing database schema. what happened when app will be updated on user's device ? would all data in old database removed or just remains with same database and data ?

2.For example I have an app which is on appstore and containing sqlite database. After sometime I want to update app version with changed database schema. what happened when app will be updated on user's device ? its must changed the DB file but how can we save old data entries those are in old DB version. I have read many posts but still confused which approach I should use.
Thanks in advance for Helping

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple. When updating the application documents folder remains intact, so you can assume that the user data continues to be available.

For case 2 make sure you do not compromise the data in your update routines at the first start after the update. The app should detect that it is in a new version and modify the schema (e.g. via SQL scripts) while taking care of not deleting user data.

Comment: @Deniel Welcome to Stackoverflow by the way. It is customary here to tick the check mark when an answer has been helpful.